# SQL in VBA: filtering part of DB row

Tags: sql, vba

I have a code which takes data from a DB with a SQL statement with 2 WHERE conditions. What I want is to paste the recordset into sheet2 . Each recordset has 13 columns of data. Problem is, when I take the recordset and I paste them into sheet2, the pasted columns are only the first 3.To note that from column 4 to 10 there can be empty columns
Do you know what could be the problem?

UPDATE 3: Updated question and code according to feedback

```
'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the data from table.


With Recordset
      SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE [PRini] = '" & var & "' or [QAini] = '" & var & "' "
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
    'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
     rs.Open SQL, cnn

    'If not, write the recordset values in the sheet.
     Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs 'PROBLEM: The pasted row is not the full one in access, but only the first 3 columns. from the 4th to the 10th there are no data, from 11th to 13th there are but are not taken
```

Comment: Do you mean that there are some columns from the recordset missing, or that the filter in Excel isn't working as you intended?  A bit more detail would help.

Comment: I have added some info, let me know if it's clearer now, thank you

Comment: not really sorry.  Immediately after the command `Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` is the data on Sheet2 as you expect?

Comment: I think you got the problem. The data is pasted in sheet2 but it's not all the rows data I need, some parts are "missed". So when I take the recordset with the SQL statement appears all is good (copies the full row from Access) but when it pastes them I only have 3 column of the 15 that exist

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly the problem, and there are all sorts of things wrong with this code.  The issues which may be related to your problem include:

- `SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE [PRini] or [QAini]  = '" & var & "' "` will return rows where either PRini is TRUE or QAini = var.  Did you mean `SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE [PRini] = '" & var & "' or [QAini]  = '" & var & "' "` - i.e. where PRini = var or QAini = var?
- the autofilter is applied to the table "Table1", but there is nothing to say this table has the same dimensions as the recordset in either direction (`copyFromRecordset` does not create or populate a table, it just pastes the values straight in to the worksheet).  If you need the data in a table, use the `QueryTable.Connection`, `QueryTable.CommandType` and `QueryTable.CommandText` properties to connect the table to the SQL server directly (see the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-object-excel)).  Or apply the autofilter to the range containing the data (`Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion` will do).
- there is nothing in the code that references the current date.  The code from `'Filter for the date` onwards just copies the visible cells from the first two columns into a listBox control.

Why not include the date condition in the SQL?  That would be the approach I would use (e.g. `SELECT * FROM Data WHERE ([PRini] = 'something' OR [QAini]  = 'something')  AND [MyDateColumn] < DATE();`)

Comment: Great  help! Your first point highlighted a problem I didnt consider, even thought there is a date filtering happening somewhere because if [PRini] TRUE, I would still not see it if it was older compared to today, but you still managed to help! Regarding the second point, I need to paste the values I take from SQL into sheet2 , where there isn't a table

Comment: Maybe the problem is the fact that the column 4th in Access can be empty. This might be the cause for the SQL statement to not taking the full row?

Comment: I have tried to use your filtering for the date, but it's not working. The data are in an access  DB and error I get is “Undefined function 'Convert' in expression”

Comment: sorry, didn't spot that you were using Access.  i've changed the syntax - should work now?